# How to enable / disable buttons in java, eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, button, awt

How can I disable buttons with the press of one button and when the task that the button which has been pressed was assigned to has been done then I want all the buttons to be enabled. for example;

```
UpButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DownButton.setEnabled(false);
        LeftButton.setEnabled(false);
        RightButton.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.printline("Up Button");

    }
});
DownButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        UpButton.setEnabled(false);
        LeftButton.setEnabled(false);
        RightButton.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.printline("Down Button");


    }
});
LeftButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DownButton.setEnabled(false);
        UpButton.setEnabled(false);
        RightButton.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.printline("Left Button");

    }
});
RightButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        DownButton.setEnabled(false);
        LeftButton.setEnabled(false);
        UpButton.setEnabled(false);
        System.out.printline("Right Button");

    }
});
```

I have tried to do it but it does not work. What I want is, for example, my Upbutton is printing out ("Up button"), so when a user presses this button I want all the other buttons to be disabled until it has finished doing the command that it was suppose to do, in this case print out a text but later on I will be adding things like adding up two user inputs e.g. I will have a button that will ask the user to type number 1 and then number 2 and then the computer will add them up and during this process I want all the buttons to be disabled expect the one that has been clicked on, until the user has given all numbers and the computer has given the output.

I hope I have explained myself properly, if not please let me know and I will try my best to give more information. Thanks in advance.

Comment: just one question, please this question is about ....

Comment: after dot isn't posible to use code tag (never hands up, maybe someone do that with html formatting)

Comment: use JRadioButtons added to ButtonGroup, with little effort is possible by using JToggleButtons

Comment: @mKorbel: yep, exactly.

Comment: You need to learn about the [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) API. You can disable the buttons and kick off the worker. When it's done it can then re-enable the buttons.

Comment: @BoristheSpider: I'm not sure that a SwingWorker is what he wants since his processes seem trivial and quick, if I'm interpreting this correctly. It almost sounds as if he wants to launch a JOptionPane or other modal JDialog, but I'm not 100% sure on this.

Comment: @Hovercraft my thought was that the OP wanted to do some background task and not allow another one to be run until it is finished. Maybe you're right. Question is somewhat unclear...

Comment: Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 1):

How about using `Command` objects? Each command object might have `execute()` and `canExecute()` methods at least. Then;

```
btnA.setEnabled( cmdA.canExecute() );
btnA.addActionListener( event-> { 
    cmdA.execute();
    btnB.setEnabled( cmdA.canExecute() );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That seems right. Maybe you want them invisible instead of disabled...

In that case:

```
LeftButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

DownButton.setVisible(false);
UpButton.setVisible(false);
RightButton.setVisible(false);
System.out.printline("Left Button");
```

Here´s an example of something that works:

```
private void jButtonChangeChampActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                   
    jComboBoxPlayer.setEnabled(true);
    jComboBoxChampion.setEnabled(true);
    jButtonSelecionar.setVisible(true);
    jButtonMagias.setVisible(false);
}
```

Comment: Hi, Rafael both with my method DownButton.setEnabled(false); and your method DownButton.setVisible(false); it says the buttons cannot be resolved. I want the buttons to be visible but disabled if one button is pressed.

Comment: Are the buttons declared(private javax.swing.JButton UpButton;)? Have you imported javax.swing.JButton? Probably so, right?

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this:

```
UpButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    UpButtonActionPerformed(evt);

        }
    });

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    DownButton.setEnabled(false);
    LeftButton.setEnabled(false);
    RightButton.setEnabled(false);
    System.out.printline("Up Button");
}
```

It works here...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to Set the Button Disabled , You can use the

btnExample.setDisable(true); // This will disable the Button

btnBreak.setVisible(false); // This will make the button Disappear visually only.

Hope this help guys.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first disable the other buttons, finish your task and then enable the buttons again.

For example:

```
UpButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        // first disable all other buttons 
        DownButton.setEnabled(false);
        LeftButton.setEnabled(false);
        RightButton.setEnabled(false);

        System.out.println("Up Button");
        // do rest of your tasks here. 

        // now enable them again
        DownButton.setEnabled(true);
        LeftButton.setEnabled(true);
        RightButton.setEnabled(true);

    }

});
```

Similarly, setup the Listeners for the other buttons.

---

Hope this helps!